# How to align a button offset to the left or right of a form with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Still relatively new to Bootstrap so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

How do I offset my button to the left or right of a centred form using Bootstrap? I tried using   'justify-content: flex-end;'  but that only put it at the edge of the page. I tried making the position relative and styling it that way but it was not responsive.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>
  <title>PHP</title>

   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="php.css">


</head>



<body>

<form>

  <div class="form-group centered">
     <div class="col-md-6">

       <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">

     </div>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group centered">

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>

     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">

   </div> 
 </div>


  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>





<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

here is the css:

```
.centered {

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
   justify-content: center; 

 }

body {

     padding: 10px;

 }
```

Comment: Do you want password beneath email address or in the same line?

Comment: @manhan beneath the email address.

Comment: Then, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used bootstrap 3 links. You should use `bootstrap-4.1` links.

- Use `col-md-6` for the `form`.
- Use `mx-auto` for the `form`  to align it in the center.
- Use `text-right` instead of `text-center` to align the button in the right. By default, it is in the left side

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKeJeQ

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remove center class and use margin to center the form
see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/71642/)

```
<form>

  <div class="form-group ">
     <div class="col-md-6">

       <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">

     </div>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group centered">

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>

     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">

   </div> 
 </div>


  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

css

```
  form{
       position:relative;
       width:80%;
       margin:0 auto;
     }
```